# Ipywidgets are not displayed propperly in VS Code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, jupyterhub

It seems that some of my Jupyter Notebook/VS Code settings are not set up correctly, resulting in different outputs for the same Python code using Ipywidgets on different instances. **What do I need to change in order to see all widgets the same way regardless of the instance on which I'm running the code?**

Below you can find of the used versions and the corresponding output:

**1. Jupyter Hub (via Firefox)**

- Python 2.7.18
- IPython: 8.4.0
- ipykernel: 6.15.1
- pywidgets: 8.0.1
- jupyter_client: 7.3.5
- jupyter_core: 4.11.1
- jupyter_server: 1.18.1
- jupyterlab: 3.4.5
- nbclient: 0.6.7
- nbconvert: 7.0.0
- nbformat: 5.4.0
- notebook: 6.4.12
- qtconsole: not installed
- traitlets: 5.3.0

[Code output of Jupyter Hub via Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYmtO.png)

**2. Juyter Notebook (hostet locally, via Firefox)**

- Python 3.10.6
- IPython: 8.4.0
- ipykernel: 6.15.3
- pywidgets: 8.0.1
- jupyter_client: 7.3.5
- jupyter_core: 4.11.1
- jupyter_server: 1.18.1
- jupyterlab: 3.4.5
- nbclient: 0.6.7
- nbconvert: 7.0.0
- nbformat: 5.4.0
- notebook: 6.4.12
- qtconsole: not installed
- traitlets: 5.3.0

[Code output of Jupyter Notebook hosted locally via Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II8HU.png)

**3. VS Code**

- Python 3.10.6
- IPython: 8.4.0
- ipykernel: 6.15.3
- pywidgets: 8.0.1
- jupyter_client: 7.3.5
- jupyter_core: 4.11.1
- jupyter_server: 1.18.1
- jupyterlab: 3.4.5
- nbclient: 0.6.7
- nbconvert: 7.0.0
- nbformat: 5.4.0
- notebook: 6.4.12
- qtconsole: not installed
- traitlets: 5.3.0

[Code output of VS-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pl3R.png)

**Note**: In the VS Code output the text field does not appear. Changing the presentation in the cell by clicking on the three dots and then on Change Presentation gives the following options:

[Presentation option in output cell (VS Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aISRn.png)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with VS Code: can display `IntSlider` and others but some like `Text` won't display. If I add them as children to an `Hbox` the box does not display at all.